# Is there an Intellij plugin to align values in a .properties file?

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

Is there a plugin that allows formatting properties files in IntelliJ?  Basically I want to format

```
prop1 = thing
some.otherprop = other thing
```

to become

```
prop1          = thing
some.otherprop = other thing
```

Is there a setting in IntelliJ for this or a plugin to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of a plug-in that can do it. Please [submit a request to YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) and this feature may appear in the later IntelliJ IDEA versions (right now there is no any code style configuration available for `.properties` files).